# Git Branch changing when navigating into new directory

Tags: git

I'm in a feature branch (blue in git bash) and when I navigate into my folder the branches (in blue) changes to master.

I think I added this directory to master before using git branch to make the branches. I also pulled from master and my feature branch is up to date. Why can I see the directory but not navigate into it?

Answer (score 2):

If you see the branch changing (to `master`) just by going to a subfolder, it is possible said subfolder represent the root directory of a *nested* Git repository.

That would be a Git repository inside a Git repository: check if that directory (where you see `master`) includes a `.git/` subfolder.

Then decide if its content should be part of your main repository or not.